# Getting positional argument error

Tags: python, folium

I have dataset of Covid-19 total death, cases and country name I want to add all details in map using folium model but I'm stuck.

```
## General Libraries for data analysis
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
#for visulization
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import folium
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
# read dataset
data = pd.read_csv("covid_data.csv")
data.head()
# maiking map
m = folium.Map(location=[20,0], tiles="OpenStreetMap", zoom_start=2)
for i in range(0,len(data)): 
   folium.Marker(
       location=[data.iloc[i]['Latitude'], data.iloc[i]['Longitude']],
       popup=data.iloc[i]['Total_Case'], +' ' + data.iloc[i]['Total_Death'], +' ' + data.iloc[i][ 'Country'],
    ).add_to(m)
# # Show the map again
m
```

it is showing error like this

```
 File "C:\Users\darshan\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_2388/391102649.py", line 16
    ).add_to(m)
    ^
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
```

In map by using popup I want to display all total death total cases and name of country.

Answer (score 1):

In Line 15, try

```
popup=data.iloc[i]['Total_Case'] +' ' + data.iloc[i]['Total_Death'], +' ' + data.iloc[i][ 'Country'],
```

Instead of

```
popup=data.iloc[i]['Total_Case'], +' ' + data.iloc[i]['Total_Death'], +' ' + data.iloc[i][ 'Country'],
```

(there is a comma behind *['Total_Case']* which interrupts the string concatenation and is interpreted as a new argument)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it shows the same error

Comment: Remove the comma behind total_deaths'] as well